# Issues with using isalpha() C++

Tags: c++

Very much a newbie to C++ here. I'm writing a very simple program that checks to see if a character in a string containing two characters is alphabetical. If a character is alphabetical, I want to replace it with the character '_', however, there seems to be an issue with my if statement and I cannot figure it out for the life of me. I feel like the fix is simple, but cannot think of the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string passCode;

   cin >> passCode;

   if (isalpha(passCode.at(0)) == true){
      passCode.at(0) = '_';
   }
   if (isalpha(passCode.at(1)) == true){
      passCode.at(1) = '_';
   }


   cout << passCode << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you look at the description of what `isalpha` returns in your textbook or manual that you're using. Read the description of `isalpha`'s return value very, very carefully, and keep reading that description until you see the problem.

Comment: You do not need to it use `== true`. It will work without.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) does not return `bool`, it returns an `int` -- and it is only guaranteed to return a nonzero value on success.

When you compare:

```cpp
if (isalpha(passCode.at(0)) == true)
```

You are implicitly converting `true` to an integral value (in this case, `1`) -- which is not the result that `std::isalpha` is returning.

You can fix this easily by removing the `== true` and allowing the `int` value to be implicitly converted to `bool` instead:

```cpp
if (isalpha(passCode.at(0))){
   passCode.at(0) = '_';
}
if (isalpha(passCode.at(1))){
   passCode.at(1) = '_';
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c8qrY9)</kbd>